# Extracting text from image for pokemon go

Tags: image-processing

Ok I am looking to make a discord bot. I am looking to take photos like these that get uploaded and parse some info out of them.

[image 1](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/341245947977662485/438451455125487618/Capture_2018-04-24-16-29-13.png)

[image 2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/341245947977662485/438459390060920853/image.png)

[image 3](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/341245947977662485/438025062264733707/Screenshot_20180423-121454.png)

[image 4](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/341245947977662485/437683078983581696/image.png)

[image 5](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/341245947977662485/437668818085740544/image.png)

What I need out of each one is the part at the top that gives the location, the time in either the pink oval or orange oval. If it is an egg I also need the number of faces below the time (Tiers 1-5). If it is a pokemon I need the name of the pokemon.

On the positive side if it helps I can have a list of the different options for the location and pokemon names. Im not sure the best way to match close matches though. Should only be 10-20 pokemon at a given time (Across all tiers) although there are ~100 gym locations around here.

As for language I am only familiar with VB.Net although I can muddle my way around in a few others.

Comment: Text recognition is not exactly a trivial operation...

Comment: I am somewhat aware of this. I am not looking for somebody to do this for me but possibly some pointing in the right direction.